# How to dim the area around a view in android?

Tags: android, layout, view, camera, overlay

I am trying to make an activity that needs to show square area as focused. 
So far I have done this.

[image]

Now what I want is to dim the area outside the square. 
Using framelayout dims the whole view. I only want to dim the region outside the square.

Comment: You can have the background color be translucent black to make a shadow. Maybe post your whole layout xml so it will be clear where to put it. @pryankvex

Answer (score 6):

You can paint a black semitranslucent rectangle and then draw an inner rectangle with `paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_OUT));`

As I know nothing about your layout, I'm giving a full example with a `CustomOverlay` class:

**my_activity.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <fragment
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

    <mypackage.CustomOverlay
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

(I'm using a map as base view instead of a camera)

**CustomOverlay.java**

```
public class CustomOverlay extends LinearLayout {
    private Bitmap windowFrame;

    public CustomOverlay(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomOverlay(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CustomOverlay(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public CustomOverlay(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    }

    @Override
    protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.dispatchDraw(canvas);

        if (windowFrame == null) {
            createWindowFrame();
        }
        canvas.drawBitmap(windowFrame, 0, 0, null);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isClickable() {
        return false;
    }

    protected void createWindowFrame() {
        windowFrame = Bitmap.createBitmap(getWidth(), getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas osCanvas = new Canvas(windowFrame);

        RectF outerRectangle = new RectF(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());

        Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        paint.setColor(Color.argb(150, 0, 0, 0));
        osCanvas.drawRect(outerRectangle, paint);

        paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_OUT));
        RectF innerRectangle = new RectF(100, 200, getWidth() - 100, getHeight() - 200);
        osCanvas.drawRect(innerRectangle, paint);

        paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(5);
        paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        osCanvas.drawRect(innerRectangle, paint);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isInEditMode() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
        super.onLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);
        windowFrame = null;
    }
}
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

Comment: How would you do it so the rectangle view can be resized and the dim view will follow closely enough so its perfectly fluid?